# Spring boot custom constraint validator not injected with service

Tags: spring, validation, dependency-injection, spring-boot, spring-java-config

This is my custom validator which checks some fields availability. The UserRepository is null, therefore the validator is not injected with it.

```
public class AvailableValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Available,String> {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private Available.Field type;

    public void initialize(Available usernameAvailable) {
        this.type = usernameAvailable.type();
    }

    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (userRepository == null) System.out.println("\n\n------USER REPOSITORY IS NULL-------\n\n");


        switch (type){
            case EMAIL:
                return userRepository.findByEmail(s)==null;
            case NUMBER:
                return userRepository.findByNumber(s)==null;
            case NAME:
                return userRepository.findByName(s)==null;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I've read on similar threads that I have to set up validator factory.
I've done this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Validator validator(){
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

But it still doesn't work. userRepository is a null. Probably I got the config wrong, first time trying java configuration.

Comment: Are AvailableValidator and UserRepository both managed by Spring (ie. are they declared as beans or annotated with @component/@repository and properly in component scan path) ?

Comment: and how do you perform the validation exactly? See also https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13327

Comment: Validation is permorfed automatically when annotation Valid is present. Available validator is not annotated with @component because i dont think it has to be, at least in old xml configuration there was no need of specyfying a bean of a specific validator class. Anyways it turns out when i add a line in properties which disables hibernates automatic validation it works

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to disabling Hibernates validation, have you tried this:

```
@Primary
@Bean
    public Validator validator(){
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
```

This would give your validator preference as suggested [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html).

Mike Kowalski

Comment: Tried this but did not work. The autowired jpa repository is still a Null

Answer (score 0):

you have to see why user repository is null.

please check the logs or check the paramaters the database configurations.

try adding a constructor in the class AvailableValidator with user repository as an arugument to the constructor .

or

provide a setter method for user repository and use autowire over that setter method.